# TRUNCATE doesn't run ON DELETE trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, ddl, truncate

I was searching on the topic of why TRUNCATE is placed in DDL instead of DML for which I found following answer here
[Why is truncate DDL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/why-is-truncate-ddl)

In this answer I found a sentence as given below

"The fact that TRUNCATE doesn't run ON DELETE triggers also sets it apart from normal DML operations"

This conflicts with [MYSQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) which says

"If the FOREIGN KEY constraint specifies DELETE CASCADE, rows from the child (referenced) table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes empty."

I am in a confused state. Please elaborate on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Although most concepts are probably common, that link belongs to a question about **Oracle**.

Comment: I think most concept about SQL are common to both MYSQL and Oracle SQL

Comment: @geeksal - triggers are an area where there can be *vast* differences between database engines.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you can quote from some reliable source that this type of behaviour of processing or not processing a trigger is for based on type of DB engine than I will surely agree with you. The given documentation link says about InnoDB however it doesn't mentioned any thing about MYISAM or any clarification regarding DB Engine Issue. Please Post an answer if you get the solution.

Comment: I was more referring to your assumption that Oracle and MySQL would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL 5.0**

> [13.1.21 TRUNCATE TABLE
>   Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> For an InnoDB table before version 5.0.3, InnoDB processes TRUNCATE
>   TABLE by deleting rows one by one. As of MySQL 5.0.3, row by row
>   deletion is used only if there are any FOREIGN KEY constraints that
>   reference the table. If there are no FOREIGN KEY constraints, InnoDB
>   performs fast truncation by dropping the original table and creating
>   an empty one with the same definition, which is much faster than
>   deleting rows one by one. (When fast truncation is used, it resets any
>   AUTO_INCREMENT counter to zero. From MySQL 5.0.13 on, the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT counter is reset to zero by TRUNCATE TABLE, regardless
>   of whether there is a foreign key constraint.)
>
> In the case that FOREIGN KEY constraints reference the table, InnoDB
>   deletes rows one by one and processes the constraints on each one. If
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint specifies DELETE CASCADE, rows from the
>   child (referenced) table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes
>   empty. If the FOREIGN KEY constraint does not specify CASCADE, the
>   TRUNCATE TABLE statement deletes rows one by one and stops if it
>   encounters a parent row that is referenced by the child, returning
>   this error:
>
> ```
> ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`test`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))
> ```
>
> ...

**MySQL 5.1**

> [13.1.34 TRUNCATE TABLE
>   Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> If there are any FOREIGN KEY constraints that reference the table,
>   InnoDB processes TRUNCATE TABLE by deleting rows one by one,
>   processing the constraints as it proceeds. If the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint specifies DELETE CASCADE, rows from the child (referenced)
>   table are deleted, and the truncated table becomes empty. If the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint does not specify CASCADE, the TRUNCATE TABLE
>   statement deletes rows one by one and stops if it encounters a parent
>   row that is referenced by the child, returning this error:
>
> ```
> ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`test`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))
> ```
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > In MySQL 5.5 and higher, TRUNCATE TABLE is not allowed for InnoDB tables referenced by foreign keys. For ease of upgrading, rewrite such statements to use DELETE instead.
>
> ...

**MySQL >= 5.5**

> [13.1.34 TRUNCATE TABLE
>   Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> - TRUNCATE TABLE fails for an InnoDB table or NDB table if there are any
>     FOREIGN KEY constraints from other tables that reference the table.
>     Foreign key constraints between columns of the same table are
>     permitted.
>
> ...

Comment: I am asking which one of the two links above misrepresent fact or somehow i have misunderstood the concept.